# How to use Objectify v6 in Vert.x on Google app engine standard

Tags: google-app-engine, vert.x, objectify

How do I get **Objectify v6** to work in **Vert.x**?

In app engine docs, Vert.x is listed as one of the platforms that can run on app engine standard.

My goal is to port a servlet based Java 8 website to vert.x on Java 17 with a datasore database.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this documentation on [Objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify) ([wiki](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki)):

> Objectify is a Java data access API specifically designed for the Google Cloud Datastore (aka the Google App Engine Datastore aka Firestore in Cloud Datastore mode). It occupies a "middle ground"; easier to use and more transparent than JDO or JPA, but significantly more convenient than the low-level API libraries that Google provides. Objectify is designed to make novices immediately productive yet also expose the full power of the Datastore.

This means that Objectify is designed specifically for both Google App Engine Datastore and Firestore in Datastore mode as they are both serverless platforms.

If you need additional information, help, or support for Objectify, you may post your question through this link on [Objectify App Engine User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/objectify-appengine).

If you want this to become a feature in future updates, you may file this as a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). This doesn't have a specific ETA but you can keep track of its progress once the ticket has been created.